# How to logout with Auth0 SDK? "You forgot to wrap your component in <Auth0Provider>"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, next.js, auth0

I'm using the `logout` function from the `useAuth0()` hook to log out. However, when I try to use it, I get the following error

```
Error: "You forgot to wrap your component in <Auth0Provider>"
```

However, it is wrapped in the Auth0Provider so I'm unsure what's causing this error.

```
  const { logout } = useAuth0();

return (
    <Auth0Provider
      domain={redacted}
      clientId={redacted}
      redirectUri={redacted}
      audience={redacted}
      cacheLocation="localstorage"
    >
      <GlobalCss />
      <AuthGuard>
        <AuthorizedApolloProvider>
          <BaseToolbar css={{justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
            <ToolbarToggleGroup type="multiple">
              <ToolbarToggleItem
                value="Users/Search"
                onClick={() => router.push('/user')}
              >
                Users/Search
              </ToolbarToggleItem>
            </ToolbarToggleGroup>
            <ToolbarToggleGroup type="multiple">
              <ToolbarToggleItem
                value="Logout"
                 // here is where i logout
                onClick={() =>  logout({ returnTo: window.location.origin })}
              >
                Logout
              </ToolbarToggleItem>
            </ToolbarToggleGroup>
          </BaseToolbar>
          <DefaultHead />
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </AuthorizedApolloProvider>
      </AuthGuard>
    </Auth0Provider>
)
```

Comment: I think you have to call `useAuth0` from a component that is wrapped inside the provider.  The one you're calling it from has the provider as a child, so it's outside of it.

Comment: @Abe that was it, thank you

Comment: Great. If you don't mind I will add it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The component you're calling `useAuth0` from is outside of the `Auth0Provider`, since the `Auth0Provider` is its child.  You'll need to call `useAuth0` from a component that is wrapped in the Provider.

As an example, you could refactor your `ToolbarToggleItem` component to take a `logoutDestination` as a prop instead of an `onClick` function.  Then, inside `ToolbarToggleItem`, get the `logout` function by calling `useAuth0` in the body of the function component.

Inside your `ToolbarToggleItem`'s return, you could have an `onPress` that would look like:

`onPress={() => logout({ returnTo: logoutDestination })`

on the component that handles touch.